# How to update inactive objects/entities

Tags: optimization, logic, game-engine

I have lots of objects in a game I programmed and I made an `inactive` state for them so they don't update all the time. I want to update only the objects within a specific range of the player. However, if I want to check if the object is inside the distance, I have to iterate over all the objects again.

I have a lot of objects so I really can't check all of them. How do big games handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many objects that do not move frequently, you can look into [oct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree)/[quad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) trees for 3d/2d games respectively. These are data structures which make it quick to weed out objects that you know aren't close to your player.

If however, your objects also move around frequently, (think a game of asteroids) you might find yourself spending more time doing bookkeeping for these structures than just checking manually.

You may also find [this](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html) link, which steps through spatial partition strategies, helpful.

Comment: +1 for the keyword *spatial partitioning*. @JamesT A simple grid is easier to implement than a Quadtree and also very efficient, if your search radius around the player does not change much (that is, its length does not change. Moving the player is not a problem).